# MacBook Pro shows folder with Question mark when it's plugged in

Tags: macbook-pro, startup, battery

For the past few months, I’m experiencing a problem when I charge my MacBook with the lid closed; the computer gets hot and when I open the lid it shows a blinking folder with a question mark inside. I have read previously that this means the MacBook can't find the start disk. But, if I pull out the charger and force quit using the power button, it boots up as regular and the problem goes away.

The laptop is a MacBook Pro 2017 without a Touch Bar. I tried to fix the problem by resetting the SMC and NVRAM, reformatting the disc, and also reinstalling macOS but nothing seems to work.

From what I have seen on the web, it can be a problem with the logic board, SSD, or perhaps the battery. I also had issues with the battery a couple of months prior when it shuts down a minute after opening the lid after a night's rest. It shows that a have around a 50% battery level and if I plug it in the MacBook starts up again and shows a 50% battery level and can then unplug the cord and continue using the Mac.

My question is whether to change the battery in the hope to solve the problem or should I start looking at a new MacBook?

[image]

Comment: It's some sort of hardware problem, clearly. Take it to an Apple Store or other authorised Apple tech. The Store will diagnose it for free, and you can then decide whether you want to pay for the repair. There's no point buying a new battery if it's actually the logic board.

Comment: I called Apple Support for help and they said that they need to take it in for a better look and it would set me back 60$ just for the research. Don't live in the US so may have other terms.

Comment: What country are you in? You should be able to book a "Genius" appointment and get a diagnosis without any payment. I'm in the UK, and have done this several times.

Comment: I'm in Sweden and don't have an Apple Store in my city

Comment: There's no Apple-authorised repair shop in the whole city?

Comment: It makes no sense that NVRAM would become corrupted with a power supply attached to mains is connected.  To verify that your storage is working, try putting the Mac into Target Disk Mode and using a friends/colleagues Mac to boot from it.  If it’s reliable, you can rule out the SSD.

Comment: Also, if you have the technical skill open the back and detatch the battery.  Your Mac should be able to boot without it.  If not, you might have an issue with the logic board and the power circuitry.